# How to use Simple Form and Direct Upload ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, rails-activestorage

I'm having a trouble when I try to use Simple Form gem for upload video. I'm using ActiveStorage and local storage for this.
My form looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @film do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :title, as: :string
  = f.input :description, as: :string
  = f.input :cover_img, as: :file

  = f.input :film_link, as: :file, direct_upload: true
  = f.button :submit
  = link_to 'back', :back, class: 'btn btn-secondary'
```

I've followed instruction on here https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html
So I've included js and css files in my app. But that won't work. It looks like there's some troubles with passing `direct_upload: true` via simple_form.
I've also find article https://phase2online.com/blog/2018/10/03/easily-upload-files-with-active-storage-in-rails-5-2/ and pull git repo from  [here](https://github.com/bratta/file-upload-demo)

An this works on when you'll use form_for on your _form. When I change form to use simple_form gem(instead of form_form use simple_form_for) it won't work.

Anyone have an idea why this is not working please?
I use ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 5.2.3 and simple_form (5.0.1)

Comment: Instead of `f.input`, try using `f.file`

Comment: Using f.file_field instead of f.input will make this direct upload working but then all error messages from simple form are not shown. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

There're is the way to make this work.

1. We can change f.input to f.file_field as [hashrocket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944700/hashrocket) suggest - but then validation of simple form will not work, and perhaps we have to add class to this input plus extra div before.
2. We can add html attribute to the f.input.

For me this is working I hope it will help someone else too.

```
= simple_form_for @film do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :title, as: :string
  = f.input :description, as: :string
  = f.input :cover_img, as: :file, input_html: { data: { direct_upload_url: '/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads' } }
  = f.input :film_link, as: :file, input_html: { data: { direct_upload_url: '/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads' } }
  = f.button :submit
  = link_to 'back', :back, class: 'btn btn-secondary'
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: instead of hardcoding the direct upload url (`direct_upload_url: '/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads'`) use the url helper's path: `direct_upload_url: rails_direct_uploads_url` (I use the absolute URL here because the default form handler does this, too when using `direct_upload: true`)

Answer (score 3):

These days (rails 6.x), you shouldn't need to specify `as: file` (simple form should figure this out via reflection) and you can just pass `direct_upload: true` to `input_html`:

```
= simple_form_for @film do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.input :title, as: :string
  = f.input :description, as: :string
  = f.input :cover_img, input_html: { direct_upload: true }
  = f.input :film_link, input_html: { direct_upload: true }
  = f.button :submit
  = link_to 'back', :back, class: 'btn btn-secondary'
```

Verify it's doing the right thing by looking at the generated html. You should see an attribute like this on each `input` which is of `type="file"`:

```
data-direct-upload-url="https://<your app server>/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads"
```

@anka's suggestion to [create a custom input type](/a/62978847/320737) is a good one, but you could also edit the default simple form wrappers for file types if you know all your files will be direct uploads to S3.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to simply add a custom input for that to avoid repetition within your view files. Put this in the file `app/inputs/direct_upload_file_input.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
class DirectUploadFileInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::FileInput
  def input_html_options
    super.merge({ direct_upload: true })
  end
end
```